# How to authorize a specific page with CanCan and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, rolify

I have a resource for `students` with CRUD methods. Only people with certain roles can read, update, manage, etc the `students` resource. I specified that in my `ability.rb` file. However, now I want students (who normally have no access to the `students` resource) to be able to access only their attendance records in `/students/:student_id/attendances`. How can I allow that?

Answer (score 0):

```
can :read, Attendance, student_id: user.id
```

This should work.

I suppose this should allow access to `attendances_controller#show` when current user id has the same value of  `student_id` column of attendance that is being accessed.

Comment: This is not an Attendance resource. It's under the students controller.

Comment: I think I understand what you're suggesting. In my students controller, I do load Attendance records. So I guess that makes sense what you wrote. Except it doesn't work :(.